# Golang add custom os.File to os.Stdout

Tags: file, go, io, stdout

I'm trying to write output to a file whenever I print something to the console. There didn't seem to be any nice examples out there using a continuous stream, but rather reading a single value so I came up with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type ahhh struct {
    *os.File
    __writer io.Writer
}

func (me *ahhh) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return me.__writer.Write(b)
}

func write_print_to_file(file_name string) {
    file, _ := os.OpenFile(file_name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    new_stdout := &ahhh{file, io.MultiWriter(file, os.Stdout)}

    os.Stdout = new_stdout
}

func main() {
    write_print_to_file("output.log")
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

For some reason `os.Stdout = new_stdout` doesn't want to work. I'm fairly certain this should be an allowed assignment as I use something of similar structure in my FUSE file system, so I'm curious why `os.Stdout` doesn't want to accept my inherited `os.File`.

Alternatively if this really isn't possible any good suggestions for making a continuous data stream to a file?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> $ go doc os.stdout
> var (
>   Stdin  = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
>   Stdout = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdout), "/dev/stdout")
>   Stderr = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/dev/stderr")
> )
>     Stdin, Stdout, and Stderr are open Files pointing to the standard input,
>     standard output, and standard error file descriptors.
>
>     Note that the Go runtime writes to standard error for panics and crashes;
>     closing Stderr may cause those messages to go elsewhere, perhaps to a file
>     opened later.
> ```

---

> ```
> $ go doc os.newfile
> func NewFile(fd uintptr, name string) *File
>     NewFile returns a new File with the given file descriptor and name. The
>     returned value will be nil if fd is not a valid file descriptor. On Unix
>     systems, if the file descriptor is in non-blocking mode, NewFile will
>     attempt to return a pollable File (one for which the SetDeadline methods
>     work).
> ```

---

> ```
> $ go doc -u os.file
> type File struct {
>   *file // os specific
> }
>     File represents an open file descriptor.
>
> func Create(name string) (*File, error)
> func NewFile(fd uintptr, name string) *File
> func Open(name string) (*File, error)
> func OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm FileMode) (*File, error)
> func newFile(fd uintptr, name string, kind newFileKind) *File
> func openFdAt(fd int, path string) (*File, error)
> func openFileNolog(name string, flag int, perm FileMode) (*File, error)
> func (f *File) Chdir() error
> func (f *File) Chmod(mode FileMode) error
> func (f *File) Chown(uid, gid int) error
> func (f *File) Close() error
> func (f *File) Fd() uintptr
> func (f *File) Name() string
> func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) ReadAt(b []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) Readdir(n int) ([]FileInfo, error)
> func (f *File) Readdirnames(n int) (names []string, err error)
> func (f *File) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)
> func (f *File) SetDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) SetReadDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) SetWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) Stat() (FileInfo, error)
> func (f *File) Sync() error
> func (f *File) SyscallConn() (syscall.RawConn, error)
> func (f *File) Truncate(size int64) error
> func (f *File) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) WriteAt(b []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) WriteString(s string) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) checkValid(op string) error
> func (f *File) chmod(mode FileMode) error
> func (file File) close() error
> func (f *File) pread(b []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) pwrite(b []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
> func (f *File) readdir(n int) (fi []FileInfo, err error)
> func (f *File) readdirnames(n int) (names []string, err error)
> func (f *File) seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)
> func (f *File) setDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) setReadDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) setWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error
> func (f *File) wrapErr(op string, err error) error
> func (f *File) write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
> type file struct {
>   pfd         poll.FD
>   name        string
>   dirinfo     *dirInfo // nil unless directory being read
>   nonblock    bool     // whether we set nonblocking mode
>   stdoutOrErr bool     // whether this is stdout or stderr
> }
>     file is the real representation of *File. The extra level of indirection
>     ensures that no clients of os can overwrite this data, which could cause the
>     finalizer to close the wrong file descriptor.
>
> func (file *file) close() error
> ```

---

> I'm fairly certain this should be an allowed assignment.
>
> ```
> new_stdout := &ahhh{file, io.MultiWriter(file, os.Stdout)}
> os.Stdout = new_stdout
> ```

Is it an `*os.File`? No. Why should it be allowed?

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess os.File would need to be a interface and not a struct for this to work